# A collection to save the Actions with type parameter - Cannot convert IEnumerable<dynamic> to IEnumerable<MyEntity>

Tags: c#

In the following class for Asp.Net http middleware, there is a method with type parameter (`ExportResult<T>(...)`) and a dictionary (`Exports`) to store the method with different type parameters.

```
public class ExportMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<dynamic>, string, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase, HttpContext, Task>> Exports => 
        new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<dynamic>, string, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase, HttpContext, Task>>();

    public ExportMiddleware()
    {
        Exports.Add("download1", (IEnumerable<dynamic> source, string format, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase dataOptions, HttpContext context) =>
                                  ExportResult<MyEntity>(source, format, dataOptions, context)); // Error
                                  // Cannot convert IEnumerable<dynamic> to IEnumerable<MyEntity>
    }

    private async Task ExportResult<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, string format, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase dataOptions, HttpContext context)
    {
        // ....
        // report.DataSource = loadedData.data.Cast<T>();
        // ....
    }

    // Consume the dictionary
    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        // ....
        var path = context.Request.Path.ToString();
        if (Exports.TryGetValue(path, out var func))
            return func(source, format, options, context);
        return next(context);
    }
```

1. How to resolve the error of `Cannot convert IEnumerable<dynamic> to IEnumerable<MyEntity>` on `source`?
2. Is there a way not using `dynamic`? (there is no class type parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code knows that `source` will be an `IEnumerable<MyEntity>`, then cast it as such:

```
    Exports.Add("download1", (IEnumerable<dynamic> source, string format, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase dataOptions, HttpContext context) =>
                              ExportResult((IEnumerable<MyEntity>)source, format, dataOptions, context));
```

If you want to use the calling pattern in your example, you can move the cast into your Export helper:

```
private async Task ExportResult<T>(IEnumerable<dynamic> dynamicSource, string format, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase dataOptions, HttpContext context)
{
    var source = (IEnumerable<T>)dynamicSource;
```

If the source is actually a different type of `IEnumerable<>`, but you happen to know that all the items in it will be of type `T`, use the LINQ Cast method instead:

```
private async Task ExportResult<T>(IEnumerable<dynamic> dynamicSource, string format, DataSourceLoadOptionsBase dataOptions, HttpContext context)
{
    var source = dynamicSource.Cast<T>();
```

In any of these cases, you might want to re-think whether `dynamic` is really what you want. Since `IEnumerable<>` is covariant, `IEnumerable<object>` would work just as well in all the code you've shared.

Comment: Yes, I can change `dynamic` to `object` in the code. Are they the exactly same in this case?

Comment: Yes, as long as you're not using any of the features of the `dynamic` type, they should behave the same. There's a relatively small set of cases where I would use `dynamic`. One is to enable better generic type inference based on an object's type only known at runtime. Another is when interoperating with objects from other languages like python or javascript, where you know something about the object but can't assign an actual compile-time type to it. In pretty much any other situation I find `dynamic` is unnecessary and often dangerous.